# cakephp 3.x datetime container template

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm using Cakephp 3 and Bootstrap to build a simple office tasks site.
I'm trying to replace the regular 3 inputs date thing that cakephp uses for dates. with a single input and replace that via Javascript to some fancy datepicker.
So I'm trying to do this by changing the templates cake uses to build form inputs. The docs say:

> In addition to these templates, the input() method will attempt to use distinct templates for each input container. For example, when creating a datetime input the datetimeContainer will be used if it is present. If that container is missing the inputContainer template will be used.

But I'm using that and It changes nothing. The HTML output still uses the regular inputContainer. Here's my code:

```
'Templates'=>[
            'defaultForm' => [
                'label' => '<label class="col col-md-2 control-label" {{attrs}}>{{text}}</label>',
                'input' => '<div class="col col-md-10"><input class="form-control" type="{{type}}" name="{{name}}" {{attrs}} /></div>',
                'select' => '<div class="col col-md-10"><select class="form-control" name="{{name}}"{{attrs}}>{{content}}</select></div>',
                'inputContainer' => '<div class="form-group">{{content}}</div>',
                'datetimeContainer' => '<div class="form-group"><div class="input-group date col col-md-10">{{content}}</div></div>',
                'dateWidget' => '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="{{name}}" {{attrs}} /><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>'
            ]
        ]
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I just found my error.
I was using "datetimeContainer" but the field in the database is DATE, not DATETIME. So cakephp looks for "dateContainer" when building the form HTML.
I changed :

```
'datetimeContainer' => '<div class="form-group"><div class="input-group date col col-md-10">{{content}}</div></div>',
```

to

```
'dateContainer' => '<div class="form-group"><div class="input-group date col col-md-10">{{content}}</div></div>',
```

And now it works fine.
Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: this is the most usefull answer for the date format input for the formHelper. Thank you very much dude. =)

Answer (score 0):

I solved with css follow the code:

```css
.date > select {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    width: 33.3%;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
}
.datetime > .date > select {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    width: 20%;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
}
```

ss follow the code: